# regex - excluding a specific part of an URL via regex match in gsub

Tags: regex, r, string, regex-negation, gsub

I'm working with a vector below:

```
vec <- c("http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S02000002",
         "http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S02000003")
```

I would like to remove `http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/` from the vector. My present `regex` syntax:

```
vec_cln <- gsub(replacement = "", x = vec, perl = TRUE, fixed = FALSE,
                   pattern = "([[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]]|)(?<!S\\d{8})")
```

But this leaves only last digit from vector `vec`. I'm guessing that the problem is with `\\d{8}`, however, it's not clear to me how to work around it. I tried various solutions on [regex101](https://regex101.com) but to no avail. Some examples:

- `(?<!S\d)` - this leaves second digit
- `(?<!S[[:digit:]])` - same

What I'm trying to achieve can be simply summarised: *match everything until you find a capital letter **S** and **8 digits** after.

## Notes

I want to arrive at the solution via `gsub` and `regex` I don't want to use:

- [`gsubfn`](https://code.google.com/p/gsubfn/) and proto objects
- I'm not interested in using `substr` as I may have to work with strings of variable lengths

Comment: Just an FYI. `([[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]]|)` will match nothing as well.

Comment: `.*(?=S\\d{8})` This regex would do, match and ensure it's followed by S followed by 8 digits (by a postive lookahead)  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE2aF3/1)

Comment: Is [`sub(".*(S\\d{8})", "\\1", vec)`](http://ideone.com/q7SGj8) what you are looking for? Or really, everything up to the first S+8digits: [`sub("^(.*?)S\\d{8}.*", "\\1", vec, perl=T)`](http://ideone.com/1wmfD2)? (UPDATED)

Comment: FWIW you were using a negative lookbehind, I.e: what is after this (?<!) should be preceded by what is inside, matching only last digit or just end of line

Comment: If it is possible for more than one Sxxxx, you could use the non-greedy version. And if you want to get rid of the Sxxx part use `(.*?)(?=S\d{8}).*` and substitute with `$1`

Comment: Please post what you need to obtain as the final result. Perhaps, you need to use `grep` if you want to remove some specific strings from the vector?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, it does what it should. Could you please explain? I want learn more regex.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks very much for the useful comments. I was testing various options on regex101 and couldn't extend the match of *lookahead* to other characters. I was only able to match one letter or digit by using positive or negative ones. Clearly I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: As it is now, you aren't clear as to what the expected outcome is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the result using

```
sub(".*(S\\d{8})", "\\1", vec)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/q7SGj8)

With `.*`, we match any amount of (`*` - 0 or more) any characters but a newline up to the `S` followed by 8 digits (`S\\d{8}`). Since `(S\\d{8})` is inside unescaped parentheses, the substring matched by this subpattern is placed into a capture group #1. With `\\1` backreference, we restore the captured text in the result.

See more about [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) and [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) at regular-expressions.info.

NOTE: if you have more text after `S`+`8 digits`, you can use

```
sub("^.*(S\\d{8}).*$", "\\1", vec)
```

Comment: Why using `[\s\S]` and not just `.` ? As the two are complementary it seems over-complicating the regex

Comment: @Tensibai: This is true. I am just more accustomed to PCRE-based regexps, where `.` does not match a newline without setting a singleline mode.

Comment: Indeed, it would need the multi-line modifier at start of the regex. But I think it makes it more readable.

Comment: @Tensibai: Thank you for the comment, I removed the unnecessary alternative solution to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is with slightly prettier syntax:

```
library(rex)
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

regex_1 = rex("S", digits)

vec <- c("http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S02000002",
         "http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S02000003")

vec %>% stri_extract_last_regex(regex_1)
```

Comment: It's definitely very readable but requires quite a lot of libraries.